# wrong Subset sum in O(n^2)

Tags: dynamic-programming, subset, subset-sum

I know this code/logic is wrong for solving the subset sum problem, but can't seem to understand why.

Calculate the sum of all possible subsets and check if any is equal to the required sum. This would be done in O(n^2) which is obviously wrong as I can solve this via DP O(n*sum).

Thank you.

```
int main() {
    long long int t,n,i,j;
    scanf("%lld",&t);
    while(t--)
    {   
        long long int p[1005][1005],s[1005][1005]={0};
        long long int a[1005],sum;
        long long int counter=0;
        scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&sum);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        s[0][0]=a[0];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(i==j)
                {
                    s[i][j]=a[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    s[i][j]=a[j]+s[i][j-1];
                }
            }
        }
        int flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(s[i][j]==sum)
                    flag++;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
            cout<<1<<endl;
        else
            cout<<0<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, Subset sum is NP complete. If you can solve it in faster than exponential time for all problem instances, then you would win all kinds of prizes.

Comment: I know it's wrong, I'm just asking for the flaw in the logic.

Comment: Have you read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: I have added the code. I have properly interpreted the problem wrong, just trying to understand the mistake. I know about the problem and that it is NP complete, and how to do it using Recursion and DP. Just a random doubt I had.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is the output of the implementation other than expected or is it unclear how to bound the running time?

Comment: Logically, I am calculating the sum of all possible subsets and then comparing and checking if any subset is equal to the required sum. When I run this with some random test cases, it works fine, when I submitted it on a practice problem on codechef, it got WA. As I think the running time would be O(n^2) (fairly new to Big O notation), and the problem is obviously NP complete, so I know my solution is wrong. What I'm wondering is, where is the error. Possibly a test case for which this fails?

Comment: What is the exact meaning of s[i][j]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is simply that you are not calculating the sum of all subsets. That's why your code looks much faster than what it really takes.

See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Thank you! A possible test case for which this would fail so I could understand better?

Comment: @someone1 - There are 2^N subsets - you are only calculating N^2 subsets. Example: Assume N=20. Where do yo calculate the sum of the subset consisting of element number 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19 ? You don't.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. I just realised the problem I had solved this for mentioned subARRAYs, so I only calculated the continuous subsets! Thank you so much, a very stupid question, I should have tried a bit more myself. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `s[i][j]` just records `a[i]+a[i+1]+...+a[j]`. In fact, you need to record the sums for all subsets of `a[i...j]`, which should be `2^(j-i)`. You code should fail easily if you targeted sum is not a sum of a continuous subset.